# Extact match the trimming_text in the rtrim function

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, character-trimming, postgresql-13

If I run the following query in Postgres or Snowflake, it will remove **`test`** from the end of the input string, even though the trimming text is **`best`**:

```
SELECT rtrim('rtrimtest', 'best');
```

See:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kKYwe5tNLpVoacM2q1nJY7/0

However, I need to rtrim to only remove if the trimming text is an *exact match*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the characters doesn't matter for rtrim(). 
`rtrim('rtrimtest', 'best')` is the same as `rtrim('rtrimtest', 'stbe')`

On Postgres you can use regex_replace() for what you want to do:

```
regexp_replace('rtrimtest', 'best$', '');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3b2baf5444d8d389fbe90ec677e386f)